# Use UbunuOne Share instead of YouSendit as Thunderbird filelink

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird

I think the title says it all. 
I have a 25GB U1 account and I like the option provided in Thunderbird to upload large e-mail attachments to YouSendit. 
Is there a way to use U1 instead of YouSendit? 
I could obviously publish the file via U1 and copy the weblink into the mail body. But I'd like to be able to have the step happen automatically when files exceed a certain size. Having said this, I kind of expected to see U1 as an option in the Thunderbird Edit->Preferences->Attachments menu.

Comment: That really sounds like a good **Add-on** idea. But from your Ubuntu one files page , you can directly send the link to them .

Comment: I agree, but sometimes it's handy if you are typing a mail and at some point you want to include a large file without leaving the mail. Instead before you send it Thunderbird would ask you whether to mail or link it - just as it does with Yousendit.

Comment: Yeah,  it is **Really** a handy feature , looking forward to see it implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UbuntuOne support in Thunderbird Filelink is under development in [Bug 744037 - Add UbuntuOne support for Filelink](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=744037).

As you can see in the bug report, it is planned to land in Thunderbird 15, and you can already test it and give feedback by using [Earlybird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/channel).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a really compelling feature, but there is currently no support for Ubuntu One as a backend for Thunderbird's filelink.